# Deployed ASP.Net application not returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, iis, windows-authentication

Please excuse my lack of information over the subject as this is my first site I am trying to deploy on IIS.

**A little background information**

I have deployed an ASP.Net MVC web application to our locally hosted IIS server. This application uses some csv files stored on a different server called our G drive. Users using this application will be various engineers from my work place that are directly connected to the network and or VPN in.

When running the code locally on my machine in IIS Express, I get data returned just fine from my services I wrote for pulling the csv data. As soon as I deploy and reach the site, if I try to call the function to  pull data I get nothing returned.

**What I have checked**

I have checked the network tab to ensure the request is going through. See picture below.

[image]

The only difference is no data is coming back.

**Settings I have tried**

- Enabled Windows Authentication on IIS
- Enabled Anonymous Authentication on IIS

**Web app information**

In the web app in visual studio if I look at the properties I have enabled Anonymous authentication.

[image]

**The Question**

Am I missing some kind of authentication or need to add authentication to the IIS server? As I said I can reach the website just fine, its just any calls to retrieve data from the G drive returns nothing.

I believe it has to do with the fact our G drive requires users to be authenticated (through windows authentication) in order to access the hard drives. So how would I go about setting up the IIS server and ASP.Net web app for this?

**UPDATE**

I was in fact catching the error in the application. When changed to just throw the error I get an internal server error.

[image]

Comment: stop using IIS express for development.

Comment: What do you mean called to the G drive "return nothing"? Generally, when things fail they return an exception. They don't just "return nothing" unless you've done something to suppress the exception.

Comment: @mason I changed the code to just throw errors and I did in fact get an internal server error. See my edit for more details.

Comment: Showing us a response saying you got an internal server error doesn't do us any good. You need to actually find out *what* that error is. Check the event logs, add logging to your application etc.

Comment: @mason I added the more detailed version. It just says it cant find the file on the \\ad.yaskawa.com drive (The G drive)

Comment: It doesn't matter if that's the G drive, you're trying to access it via a UNC path. Anyways, if you're sure the file exists at that location, it's probably a permissions issue. Make sure the user the application pool is running as has permissions to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run application on your machine in IISExpress it runs under your authentication and is able to read G drive.

For IIS to do something similar, you will need to ask your network admin to create an account specifically for your application and give it access to your G drive. Then in IIS create an application pool and run it under that newly created account. And finally run your application in IIS under that newly created pool.